# SNMP - MIB Hierarchy - what each hierarchy means and how one can create a new MIB

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I have been learning SNMP and different MIBs. Web is filled with different information related to SNMP but nothing much on MIB Hierarchy.

[image]

My query is all about MIB Hierarchy - how the nodes where decidied and which will come under what and why?

Also if in case I need to create a new MIB who will authorize it and make it publically available it?

Comment: There are several books on this topic, like https://www.amazon.ca/Understanding-SNMP-MIBs-David-Perkins/dp/0134377087 In short, you must register your own enteprise number https://www.iana.org/assignments/enterprise-numbers/enterprise-numbers, and then maintain your OIDs under it. The image you pasted clearly shows how BEA (now part of Oracle) did that.

Comment: But who maintains the MIB Hierarchy and aproves the OIDs / MIBs?

Comment: Those books cover such well. Organizations like IETF are managing the OIDs, https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3061